# verify email-adress from google sign-up - flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, multi-factor-authentication, email-verification

I try to add an **multi-factor auth** to an existing account, which **is signed-in with google**.

I get the **error "verify email first"**:

> [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17086 Need to verify email first before enrolling second factors.

So it seems like I have to verify the google email-adress.
My question is whether i have to authenticate the user **again via email and password sign-in**. With:

```
final credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: emailAddress, password: password);
```

And then link the google and email auth providers, as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking?authuser=0

Or do I have to use "Email Link Authentication", as described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth?authuser=0

Or is there a completely different, easier way to verify the email address of the google account?

used code:

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
  // Trigger the authentication flow
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await (googleSignIn.signIn());

  // Obtain the auth details from the request
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

  // Create a new credential
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  final UserCredential authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

  String? name = authResult.user?.displayName;
  final String? email = authResult.user?.providerData[0].email ;
  final String? imageUrl = authResult.user?.photoURL;

  //Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
  if (name!.contains(" ")) {
    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
  }

  print(name);
  print(email);
  print(imageUrl);
  print(authResult.user?.emailVerified);

  return authResult;
}
```

Comment: I thought that the email address of a Google account should be verified already, since Google does that as part of creating the account. Can you check the `emailVerified` property of the [`User`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, doesn't seem so, emailVerified is false

Comment: in the firebase documentation for multi-auth, following is mentioned: "Ensure your app is verifying user emails. MFA requires email verification." - but how can I do this for a google signed-in account? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to **additionally verify the email** address of a google account via "Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Links" https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth?authuser=0

Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing the problem with this minimal code:

```
var cred = await signInWithGoogle();
var user = cred.user!;
print(user);
```

The `signInWithGoogle` function there is a copy/paste from the Firebase documentation on [Signing in with Google on the web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#google):

> ```
> Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
>   // Create a new provider
>   GoogleAuthProvider googleProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();
>
>   googleProvider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');
>   googleProvider.setCustomParameters({
>     'login_hint': 'user@example.com'
>   });
>
>   // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
>   return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
>
>   // Or use signInWithRedirect
>   // return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithRedirect(googleProvider);
> }
> ```

Runnable version here: https://zapp.run/edit/auth-is-google-auto-verified-zrw06uvrx06?file=lib/main.dart

When I select my gmail account, it shows that my email is verified in the `Logs` panel:

> User(displayName: Frank van Puffelen, email: xxxxx@gmail.com, **emailVerified: true**, isAnonymous: false, metadata: ...

When you run the same example, does it show `emailVerified` as `false`?

Comment: yes, emailVerified shows false but user.providerData[0].email shows the correct email. And I'm using the same code

Comment: Do you get `emailVerified: false` when you run the same link I gave? Can you show the *exact* (copy/paste) output you get, similar to what I showed above? If you modify the code to show something more, please share the link to the modified example too - so that I can run it and see what output I get.

Comment: when i use your web link emailVerified is true. But the web code is quite different. I added my complete code, see above

Comment: So you're using Flutter in a mobile app? It would be good to mention that in your question, given that the process is indeed different between web and mobile.

Comment: yes flutter in a mobile app, sorry